# Can't connect to FTP server from EC2 with ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I was able to install de FTP server (vsFTPd) with a user and password. Configured the security group:

[image]

I can connect internally from the machine with "ftp localhost", but trying with filezilla from another machine I get *Connection timed out*. The configuration is like this:

```
pasv_addr_resolve=NO
pasv_address=X.X.X.X
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=1024
pasv_max_port=1048
port_enable=YES
```

X.X.X.X is the public IP of the EC2 machine

**Edit** Adding IPTABLES info:

```
$ sudo iptables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 --dport 1024:1048 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 20:21 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: did you allow it in iptables? also I would definitely recommend using the sftp server built into openssh.  It is way more secure and easier to work with imo.

Comment: I guess so. Edited my original post to add that information.

Comment: And I'm using FTP because is a third party app that only have this option. I need FTP access.

Comment: try setting the ip in the conf to 0.0.0.0, oh and you can try connecting to it with telnet to see if it is a network error or an error with vsftpd

Comment: telnet also gives timeout

Comment: so it's definitely a netowrk error, save your iptables chains and the purge them and set the policy to allow.  If you don't want to do something that extreme add this rule: "iptables -I INPUT 1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT"

Comment: Does the instance have a public IP address (might be trivial, but definately worth checking).\

Comment: It has a public IP. I can connect to the website uploaded there. And connect by SSH with domain and IP.

Answer (score 0):

Check:

- the instance has public IP
- the subnet has internet gateway attached to default route
- the NACLs for the subnet allows your FTP ports